# Sending Section of 3D array using MPI

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmpi

I have the following 3D array.

```
U[Timesteps][X][Y]
```

With Ranges

```
Timesteps ( 0 to 100)
X ( 0 to 480)
Y ( 0 to 480)
```

I need to split the array send across the nodes for processing using MPI.

I want to split like the following way

Process ( Node 0) Should get

```
U[Timesteps][X][Y]
```

With Ranges

```
Timesteps ( 0 to 100)
X ( 0 to 200)
Y ( 0 to 200)
```

and 
Process ( Node 1) Should get

```
U[Timesteps][X][Y]
```

With Ranges

```
Timesteps ( 0 to 100)
X ( 201 to 480)
Y ( 201 to 480)
```

Likewise I can split for as many nodes that becomes available at run time. ( i.e spliting on x and Y with full timesteps)

Can anyone help with sample MPI Code..I am getting confused in the derived data type use of MPI for my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Something is missing here. What about `X(0 to 200) / Y(201 to 408)` and `X(201 to 408) / Y(0 to 200)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some going through some MPI tutorials I got how to send 3D arrays.
We need to use MPI_TYPE_INDEXED derived data type